# execute multiple queries No current row in the ResultSet issue

Tags: java, sql-server

i am trying to get a value from a column in another table and pass it to the SP procedure but i get

> No current row in the ResultSet

at `cs.setString(1, rsS.getString("ID")); // p_ID`

what is the correct way to do this

```
//get value P_ID based on itemnumber
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
          String sqli = "select ID,[ItemNumber] from [file].[Item] where [ItemNumber] =?";
         preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqli);
         preparedStatement.setString(1, itemcard);
         ResultSet rsS = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                                while (rsS.next())
                                    System.out.println(rsS.getString("ID"));

                                //for updating trash
                                CallableStatement cs = null;
                                String queryundo = "{ call [file].[usp_trashItem](?,?,?,?)}  ";
                                cs = con.prepareCall(queryundo);
                                cs.setString(1, rsS.getString("ID")); // p_ID
                                cs.setString(2, "U"); //p_Action(U for untrash T for Trash)
                                cs.setInt(3, 1); //p_Quantity
                                cs.setString(4, doerTicket); //p_DoerTicket
                                cs.executeQuery();
                                con.close();
            }
        }
```

and with this

```
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                    String sqli = "select ID,[ItemNumber] from [file].[Item] where [ItemNumber] =?";
                    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqli);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, itemcard);
                    ResultSet rsS = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    while (rsS.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rsS.getString("ID"));

                        //for updating trash
                        CallableStatement cs = null;
                        String queryundo = "{ call [file].[usp_trashItem](?,?,?,?)}  ";
                        cs = con.prepareCall(queryundo);
                        cs.setString(1, rsS.getString("ID")); // p_ID
                        cs.setString(2, "U"); //p_Action(U for untrash T for Trash)
                        cs.setInt(3, 1); //p_Quantity
                        cs.setString(4, doerTicket); //p_DoerTicket
                        cs.executeQuery();
                        con.close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

i get

> The executeQuery method must return a result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while (rsS.next())` does not have curly brackets so it will loop only on `System.out.println(rsS.getString("ID"));`.

Outside the loop (after `rsS.next()` returns `false`) the `ResulSet` is going to be empty.

Also probably `cs` is not holding a query but some other type of statement so you can't use `cs.executeQuery()` because it will give you an error if it does not return a result.

Try with `cs.executeUpdate()` or `cs.execute()`.

Comment: i tryed to do the  `(rsS.next()) {my statments}` but that gaved me The executeQuery method must return a result set

Comment: i was trying to see if i could solve that issue with The executeQuery method must return a result set

 by using the resultset